# Worldpay - how to send form data back to our server?

Tags: php, wordpress, worldpay

I'm integrating Worldpay with a Wordpress site - our customer completes a form on our site and is then sent to Worldpay to make the payment.

Upon success, Worldpay fetches the content of `redirect.php` from our server and displays it as a success message at secure-test.worldpay.com.

In order to return the customer back to our site a meta-refresh is implemented (if a 200 response code isn't detected by Worldpay they show a default thank you page). I therefore can't save the POST data to a session or similar.

How can I transmit the Worldpay POST data back to our server securely? I don't think that adding the data as URL parameters in the meta-refresh is an option as it would contain personal data.

Comment: I had a very similar problem, I ended up adding a link back to the site on the callback url. I have always thought there must be a better approach, so I'll watch this question with some interest :)